# Change the tab size (of the actual tabs)

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'd like to know if there is a way to control the size of tabpages within a tabcontrol. For strictly aesthetic purposes, I would like to have a blank area between the tabs & the tabpages. Think of it as a "short" tabpage, or a tabpage with a very thick top margin.

I would gladly provide an illustration but it seems I'm not allowed to do that here.

I've tried to override the tabpage size but the change is ignored. It appears that tabpages are always maximized within the tabcontrol. I've tried adjusting the padding & margin settings but it does not help. Simply increasing the tab height does not accomplish what I'm trying to do, either.

I've seen this done but I can't figure out how to do it myself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about [`Padding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried every combination I can think of on both the tabcontrol & the tabpage for both margin & padding. Nothing seems to address what I'm trying to do. How would you suggest settng this to do what I described? The existing thin separation *seems* to be the tabpage top margin, but if that were true, I'd need to set the margin/padding the same way on every tabpage. That seems like a silly implementation, so I've been focused on the tabcontrol. Maybe I'm the silly one?

Comment: Have you tried [ItemSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.itemsize.aspx)?

Comment: Try to put an image at one of the free spots and add a link to your question. The look depends a lot on the Windows style. On my machine I can't imagine what you want besides simply leaving a part of the tabpage empty. BTW, the selected tab should be one area form tab down into the page, as this is the metaphore!